# JavaFX ListView mirroring content at the end

Tags: javafx

When I add new item to my ListView, it starts mirroring all the content at the end it's layout (it's not clickable) does somebody know what can cause it? Thanks.

[image: App window]

Comment: something wrong in the code you are not showing ;) In other words: [mcve] please

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the problem.
I have the list of objects and want it to display the title of object as list node text.
The problem is that I wrongly defined the custom cell factory.

```
tagListView.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(StoreTagVoImpl item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (!empty) {
                    setText(item.getTitle());
                }
            }
        });
```

But it should be as this:

```
    tagListView.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(StoreTagVoImpl item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item == null || empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(item.getTitle());
            }
        }
    });
```